# After CiviCRM 4.7 upgrade, CRM.$ Not A Function Errors

Tags: civievent, upgrade, 4.7, javascript

After upgrading to CiviCRM 4.7, several CiviCRM related pages/functions on my site are not working and reporting errors related to CRM.$ not being defined as a function, but I can't find where it should be originally defined. Jquery appears to be loading and working okay. Also, when I access the 'CiviCRM » Administer CiviCRM » System Settings » Directories' page, only the core menu is displayed without any css formatting. None of the directories options are displayed so I can't verify/change them. Three, ReferenceError: CRM is not defined errors are reported for the page.

Comment: Found a work-around for the Directories page not displaying. Hack the  administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/templates/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/Pa‌​th.hlp to replace crmResPath with crmResURL.

Answer (score 1):

Try enclosing your jquery code in:

```
CRM.$(function($) {
$(document).ready(function () {

});
});
```